Reported speech may be ambiguous

He said he will do that on Monday

He said he will do that today


Is my understanding correct that 1 is quite ambiguous? I mean it either means that "he" wants to do something on Monday that is yet to come or that on Monday "he" stated the he will do something in the future. When it comes to 2 there's no ambiguity. Am I right when it comes to those two examples?

You are correct. However, many invented sentences that are 'ambiguous' are also unnatural and unlikely to be uttered or written, but they often seem to appear on here. A careful person would wish to be clear and so write something like 'He said he will/would do that on the following Monday, August 5'

Yes,  but in context it's rarely unclear what meaning is intended.  This question has been asked before, but I can't find it right now

Both are ambiguous.  The time phrase "on Monday" or "today" could refer to the verb "said" or the verb "do".  Moreover, "Monday" could be in any week, past or future.
Without any other context, the normal reading is based on closeness.  "Monday" is closer to "do" than "said" so the normal understanding is that he said "I'll do it on Monday".
But this is artificial and not a real problem.  In any realistic speech there is context.

@Jamkes K Could you provide some context where " on monday" refers to "said" not "do"?

Yes,  imagine if someone was asking you about when something was said.

or here "he said he would do that yesterday" context is not needed because it wouldn't make sense to assume that "yesterday" refers to "do". Correct?

No, in that sentence I'd assume (absent any strong reason otherwise) that "yesterday" refers to "would do".    Any competent English speaker would move "yesterday" to avoid ambiguity "Yesterday he said he would do it." But not every native speaker is competent all the time



He said he will do that on Monday
He said he will do that today


Example 1 is clear; he will do that on Monday.  To have the other meaning, it would possibly be
He said on Monday he will do that.
On Monday, he said he will do that.
Example 2 is similar to Example 1.  Yes, it is clear.
